# MongoDB Increment Array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, increment

Can someone help me how to properly make a update increment query for my data

For example I would like to increment the quantity of Unix Mug by **1**, by the user with email: **"user@yahoo.com"**

This one doesn't work for me

**UserData.updateOne({email: email}, { $inc : {items: [{quantity: 1}]}})**

[image]

Comment: Please share the data as **snippet** instead of image. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [positional operator (`$`)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional) as shown below:

```
db.users.updateOne({
  email: "USER_EMAIL",
  "items.productName": "Unix Mug"
}, {
  $inc: {
    "items.$.quantity": 1
  }
})
```